# Listings for plain tex

Tags: listings, verbatim, plain-tex, highlighting

Is there a package to produce syntax-colored blocks of source code in plain TeX ? A `listings` equivalent ? Or (maybe) some macro to produce a colored `tex` input for some given source code ? Is it possible to achieve something through LuaTeX ?

Comment: I suspect the easiest way might be to use Pygmentize and implement the macros it places in the parsed material to do the colouring: the parsing is tricky and is probably best done in something other than TeX!

Comment: `minted` perhaps? But I don't know actually

Comment: @Joseph if there are few macros that would be good enough!

Comment: the highlight package https://www.ctan.org/pkg/highlight  uses an external cpp program, supports many programming languages, custom "style sheets" and outputs both LaTeX and Plain TeX !

Comment: There is Knuth's `list.tex` which creates a nicely formatted listing from any file, but no highlighting unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

The syntax colored listings are solved by OPmac tricks [0124](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#hisyntax) (C syntax), [126](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#hisyntaxhtml) (html syntax) or [0152](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#hisyntaxpy) (Python syntax). You can simply extend these macros for another language, if you need. Note that referred macros need not any special external processor. All is done in classical TeX.

Comment: that's pretty cool, although I feel that it might be pretty complicated (for a novice like me) to declare a new syntax def for another language (TBF most languages these days are C-like, though)

Answer (score 4):

Knuth has developed the `list.tex` macros to produce code listings.  To produce a listing of the file `test.c` with the content

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

we input on the terminal

```bash
$ pdftex list.tex test.c <<< "\\bye"
```

and obtain the following output

[image]

---

Drawbacks:

- No syntax highlighting
- Overly long lines are *not* wrapped, but overflow the page
- Tabs are converted to γ (for whatever reason)